# Nginx Reverse Proxy To Docker Container Web Apps Giving 404

Tags: docker, nginx

I just made a fresh Ubuntu desktop vm, threw docker on it, threw Nginx on it, and pulled and ran the container yeasy/simple-web:latest, and ran it twice with the commands

`docker run --rm -it -p 8000:80 yeasy/simple-web:latest`

`docker run --rm -it -p 8001:80 yeasy/simple-web:latest`

I went over to /etc/nginx/sites-available and created a new file localhost.conf with the contents

```
server {
  listen      80;

  location /chad {
    proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
  }

  location /brock {
    proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8081/;
  }
}
```

I then created a symlink of the localhost.conf file at /etc/nginx/sites-enabled with the command

`ln -s ../sites-available/localhost.conf .`

This was all done as root.

When I curl localhost:8000 and localhost:8001 I get the correct webpage hosted in the docker container. When I curl localhost/chad or localhost/brock, I get an Nginx 404 error. I have not touched the default config for Nginx, and did not modify the Docker images

I am limited to using docker images and Nginx, so I cannot change technology stacks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're already doing this but it's worth mentioning:

You need to reload or restart Nginx whenever you make changes to its configuration.

To reload Nginx, use one of the following commands:

```
sudo systemctl reload nginx
sudo service nginx reload
```

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to mention, I am reloading the configs as well. Thanks for mentioning that though!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up being able to host both my docker containers with Nginx on the host machine with the following config following the above instructions.

```
server {
    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    listen 127.0.0.1;
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /chad {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
    }

    location /brock {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001/;
    }
}
```